# SQL query to get output

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two queries.

**First query:**

```
select files.originalfilename
from files
inner join digitalfiles on files.fileid = digitalfiles.fileid
where digitalfiles.path in (
        select *
        from Staple
        )
```

This will get the orginialfilename with extensions. Like below:

**originalfilename**

abc.doc

cool.bmp

1342.png

at.docx

**Now the second query:**

```
select ft.Extension
    ,COUNT(f.OriginalFileName) as [Count]
    ,sum(df.Length) / 1024 as [Size KB]
    ,ft.FileTypeId
    ,cast(count(f.OriginalFileName) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as decimal(18, 6)) as [Pct]
from Files f
inner join DigitalFiles df on f.FileId = df.FileId
left join FileTypes ft on df.FileTypeId = ft.FileTypeId
where f.Deleted = 1
group by ft.Extension
    ,ft.FileTypeId
```

This query will give me output as:
Extension, Count, Size KB, File ID, Percentage

I want to use the result of first query in second query and get the result.

Comment: I would like to make use of first query result and get the new output as below


Extension Count Size KB  FileTypeId Pct
pdf  2 8556  4  20.000000
docx  1 200  2  13.78
png  5 789999  3  56.6532


means to take only the extensions of file names and calculate the number, count, % etc.. as above.
hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding the question, but assuming that I do understand it, it seems that you could fairly easily take the where clause from the first

```
where digitalfiles.path in (
        select *
        from Staple
        )
```

And make it a part of the second query.

There are a number of ways you could do this ([CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms190766(v=SQL.105).aspx), [derived table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1042/using-derived-tables-to-simplify-the-sql-server-query-process/), etc...) but it seems like just adding that to the where clause is probably as easy as anything.

```
select ft.Extension
    ,COUNT(f.OriginalFileName) as [Count]
    ,sum(df.Length) / 1024 as [Size KB]
    ,ft.FileTypeId
    ,cast(count(f.OriginalFileName) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as decimal(18, 6)) as [Pct]
from Files f
inner join DigitalFiles df on f.FileId = df.FileId
left join FileTypes ft on df.FileTypeId = ft.FileTypeId
where f.Deleted = 1
AND df.path in (select * from Staple)
group by ft.Extension
    ,ft.FileTypeId;
```